# Do AppSync @connection fields pass through updates from connected fields?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

Say I have this model...

```
type Alpha {
  id: ID!
  bravos: [Bravo] @connection(name: "BravoConnection")
}

type Bravo {
  id: ID!
  alpha: Alpha @connection(name: "BravoConnection")
}
```

If I subscribe to the `updateAlpha` mutation will I receive updates if a `Bravo` contained in the `Alpha`'s bravos field is updated?

Answer (score 0):

How do you create your mutation?

If the bravos field is passed to the updateAlpha mutation and there is a subscription listening for the same id. Then the subscription would get the bravos field as well.

So as long as the mutation selection set returns the bravos field it will get updated.